# Get the data sent with javascript fetch on the sent page

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending data to a page using javascript fetch and I get the ok message in the console. How can I get this data on the php page I sent?

```
fetch("test.php", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                user_id: user_id,
                value: valueToSend
              })
            })
            .then(
              function(response) {
                if (response.ok) {
                  console.log("ok)
                } else {
                  console.log("There was an error sending the message.", response);
                }
              }
            );
```

I'm asking this. I will use the user_id and value values ​​in the test.php page, but how can I get this data there? So what should I do from the test.php page?

Comment: Change `if (response.ok) { console.log("ok)` to `if (response.ok) { document.getElementById("someElementId").textContent= response.text }` assuming you send something in the response called text

Comment: I am sending this data to test.php page, how can I get it there?

Comment: What is the code for test PHP?

Comment: test.php is a plain html page. I will use the data I sent with this fetch there

Comment: I'm asking this. I will use the user_id and value values ​​in the test.php page, but how can I get this data there? So what should I do from the test.php page?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are actually looking to get the values once they are sent to the test.php. You don't care about the response.

The simplest way would be to use the `$_GET` and `$_POST` objects.

in you case it would look something like

```
<?php
  echo($_POST['user_id'])
  echo($_POST['value'])
?>
```

This very simple example just prints the two vars that you sent. You can perform your logic here.

You are posting the data to the page, so php makes them available in `$_POST`. From there you can do with them what you wish.

**Edit**

If you are trying to view previously sent data (data sent by fetch on a different request) you will need to store that data when it gets to `index.php`.

window.location.href works because you are redirecting to the php page and giving it values via the query string.

Either write it to a file, store it in a DB, or put it in memory.

```
<?php
 if ($_POST['user_id'] != '') {
   #some sort of logic here to store the data that was just received.
   # This could be a database, writing the data itself to a file, etc.
 } else {
   # Logic to retrieve the data from store and display it.
   # You could retrieve the data from a database/file and then use `echo` to display it.
 }

   
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `$_REQUEST` object. I tend to prefer that over `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: It has been a while since I have had to really use PHP. Are there any benefits besides the obvious of not caring which method was used to send the data? I know in most RESTful systems, those are actually important to differentiate.

Comment: screen is blank

Comment: For most situations it doesn't really matter. Ideally if you know for certain you are submitting data via POST, use `$_POST`. But because `$_REQUEST` pulls from both `$_GET` and `$_POST` (`$_POST` takes priority) you are able to pull in all parameters without having to differentiate.

Comment: window.location.href = "/test.php?user_id=" + user_id + "&value=" + valueToSend; This is how it works, but I'm already sending it via fetch post, there's no need for it.

Comment: You need to update your question to define your use case better. I'm at a loss for what you expect to happen. We need a real world example to help you better. EG "When I visit test.php I would like to see the values that I previously sent via a JS fetch request" Without this, I can keep guessing at what you are trying to do but I won't be much help.

Comment: I want to use the user_id and value values ​​that I sent with fetch in the test.php page, so I will print these values ​​on the screen. but in test.php echo($_REQUEST['user_id']); When I type, the screen is blank. So the user_id, which is the data I fetch, is not coming.

Comment: See my edit. Your php page is a script that runs each time the page is loaded. It does not remember previous requests. All it knows are the variables it was passed when the page was loaded (a fetch request sends the data to the page and causes a page load).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you are trying to get. If for example if it was JSON

```
fetch("test.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user_id: user_id,
    value: valueToSend
  })
})
.then(
  function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("ok")
      return(response.json()) // The important bit. Grabs the response as JSON.
    } else {
      console.log("There was an error sending the message.", response);
    }
  }
).then(
  function(data) {
    //Does something with the data
  }
)
```

Comment: I am sending this data to test.php page, how can I get it there?

Comment: I'm asking this. I will use the user_id and value values ​​in the test.php page, but how can I get this data there? So what should I do from the test.php page?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of data is being returned you can use the `.text()` or `.json()` methods for your response.

```js
fetch("test.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user_id: user_id,
    value: valueToSend
  })
})
.then(response => {
  if(response.ok) {
    console.log("ok");
    let r = response.text();
    try { r = response.json();
    } catch(e) { }
    return r;
  } else {
    console.log("There was an error sending the message.", response);
  }
})
.then(r => {
  console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: I'm asking this. I will use the user_id and value values ​​in the test.php page, but how can I get this data there? So what should I do from the test.php page?